# How to make a table with vertical columns

Tags: tables, rotating

[image: vertical table]

I also need to have the aligned icons to each column

Comment: Load the `rotating` package and use `\turnbox{90}{column text}`

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `end{document}` that we can complie that shows what you have tride and what the problem is. This is not a "do it for me" site.